# how to generate and provision bulk users/data using postman

Tags: postman, bulk-load, jmeter-5.0

I need to generate a csv file and parallely wants to provisioned it in one of the containers, so that it cab be later used by other associated container. 
If anybody can suggest me ideas using Postman/Jmeter.?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out using Jmeter. By using json from the http requests and putting in loop for creating multiple iterations.